# Add a prefix for the default route of Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, routes, zend-controller-router

I would like to know if it is possible to change the default route of :module/:controller/:action/* to something like /my/prefix/:module/:controller/:action/*, keeping the possibility to not specify a module and/or controller and/or action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set baseUrl in application.ini

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "my/prefix/"
```

and you can ofcourse not specify module/controller/view but it will be default one = default/index/index 
unless you set up different default module/controller/view.

Comment: It worked with just `resources.frontController.baseUrl = "my/prefix/"`. Maybe I already have something else that made it work. Thanks =D

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup the front controller resource in the application ini.

```
resources.frontController.baseurl = "/my/prefix/"
```

Another thing you can do is add the prefix to each route in your resource router like this:

```
resources.router.routes.route-name.route = "/my/prefix/module/controller/action"
resources.router.routes.route-name.defaults.module = "module"
resources.router.routes.route-name.defaults.controller = "controller"
resources.router.routes.route-name.defaults.action = "action"
```